# How to handle an Oauth page redirect?

Tags: javascript, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-oauth

I've an API with Node/Express and Passport Google Oauth 2.0.

Passport handles a request, redirects to a Google login page, and then returns the result.

The problems:

- If I use XMLHTTPRequest to GET the page from the API server, the browser returns: (redirected from 'http://localhost/api/oauth') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. And the Google login page returns 405.
- If I redirect the client page to the API server page with Javascript, the Server doesn't knows where to redirect after Login because it doesn't knows the origin of the request.

So I don't have more ideas.

I've been doing research, the first problem seems be caused because Google forces to request the login page from the Server callback, not from an external resource. But it's only an assumption.

Comment: You should be able to specify the redirect destination of the oauth request. You do this in the Google oauth screen

Comment: @Liam thanks for reply. Yes, I can handle the redirect after Oauth screen. But, suppose that you have 2 different domains requesting the login to that API. How do you do the redirection? Because you don't know the origin. When you redirect to the Server page, the last origin is the Server page, so the API doesn't know the real origin.

Comment: Thinking about that problem, I could make a XHR request to the Server page appending the origin domain manually. Then I set a cookie in the Server page with that origin, and then I can redirect to the real origin page. But I don't know if this approach is the proper way.

Comment: That won't work. The OAuth is tied to the domain. If you have two different domains then you probably need to two different oauth tokens, etc.

Comment: @Liam I finally got the redirection with the simplest solution. Catching the referer header in Express, that maintains the previous domain (I thought that no), and then a simple script to always redirect to the absolute domain.

Comment: Feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)